# Laravel whereColumn on columns that have more than one word

Tags: laravel

In laravel query builder, we can do `where` query in a short way like `$query->whereColumn($value)`. But how do I do this to a column with more than 1 word? I mean, does `$query->whereCreatedAt(today())` will do where clause on 'created_at' column?

Comment: why not do `$query->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today());`, here date formats must be same

Comment: Yeah, that works. But it is even longer than just normal `where('created_at', today())` method. I am searching for the shortest way I can write it here. But many thanks for your response.

Comment: `where('created_at', today())` this does not always work correctly due to format, if you have so much problem then create a function in which you write `w()` & it will call `where()` for you

Comment: Right, now I am using `whereDate()` instead of `where()` to compare date in the query since your comment before. And I just wondering if there's a Laravel built-in method for apply where shortly for some column that has more than one word. Thank you

Comment: All the methods are written in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses), you can check.

Answer (score 1):

You are right you have to write it in CamelCase. You can even add some `and` or `or`.
From the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries)  :

**Dynamic Where Clauses**
You may even use "dynamic" where statements to fluently build where statements using magic methods:

```
$admin = DB::table('users')->whereId(1)->first();

$john = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereIdAndEmail(2, 'john@doe.com')
                    ->first();

$jane = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereNameOrAge('Jane', 22)
                    ->first();
```

For deeper insights how this work under the hood you can check the `public dynamicWhere($method, $parameters)` method in this file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php`

Cordially